# bbcomm.exe doesn't start automatically in Windows 64-bit

Tags: windows, api, 64-bit, bloomberg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Starting bbcomm in Java v3 Bloomberg API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880787/starting-bbcomm-in-java-v3-bloomberg-api)

we have a program in C# (framewrok 4.0) that connects to Bloomberg via APIv3.

All is working fine in our Windows 7 32-bit machines. When our program try to connect to Bloomberg, the bbcomm.exe starts automatically.

On a new Windows 64-bit machine, the same program hangs, because the bbcomm.exe doesn't start.

I've read this post:

[Starting bbcomm in Java v3 Bloomberg API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880787/starting-bbcomm-in-java-v3-bloomberg-api)

and also had a chat with the Bloomberg helpdesk, but without finding a real solution.

At the moment, the workaround is to start bbcomm.exe from a command-line, and after start our application.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have added an answer to the question you point to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12624119/829571